# Htaccess issue with redirection?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect `www.mysite.com/movie/name` to `www.mysite.com/movie/?url=name`
for this I have added htaccess in movie/ folder, the code I have added is below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /movie/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ index.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?id=$1
```

I am unable to redirect it, could anybody suggest me the right way to accomplish this?

Comment: Any kind of error you are getting or simply 404: Not found...?

Comment: are you trying to redirect to `www.mysite.com/movie/?url=name` or to `www.mysite.com/movie/index.php?id=name` ??

Comment: Good question from @Yazmat. Your question says one thing but your rules show something different. I answered based on the question. Please explain.

Comment: And, it is not clear either which strings are fixed. From the question it seems `movie` and `name` are dynamic (?).

Answer (score 0):

Just a small change and it should work..
Try below code and let me know whether it worked for you or not..

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ index.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html/$ index.php?id=$1
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

First off, you only need to write command `RewriteEngine On` once.

Besides, replace last rule for

`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?id=$1`

The fault was in the last backslash.